# Does SQL Server 2008 Log Truncation suspend transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, transactions

We are looking to schedule a job for transaction log truncation at regular intervals. However I'm concerned that our database is a heavy transaction DB and needs to be highly available.

If we have to implement transaction log backup and truncation at regular intervals would this suspend all transactions which are in process ?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You should find the right size for the log file, set it to that size and let it rest. You don't need to shrink during normal operations.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this article, which states that a transaction can not be deleted if the records mentioned in the logs are still active. So the answer to your question is No, Transaction log back up or truncation wont suspend the active transactions. Here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414(v=sql.105).aspx